# Twitter APi PHPにて動画の投稿

Tags: php

Twitter APIを用いて　ＰＨＰで動画ツィートを仕様と思うのですが、
何か良い資料はありませんか？

Comment: NOBUNAGAさんは、普通のツイートをすることには成功しているのでしょうか？

Comment: 成功しております。どうぞ宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

PHPは使ったことないので一般的な手順をご説明します。

画像のアップロード、本文のツイートの、二段階のAPIの実行を行います。

**画像をアップロードする**

https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json というAPIを使用します。
通常のツイートでは `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` でPOSTしますが、
通常のツイートでPOSTデータとして送り出すパラメータを、`Authorization: OAuth ～` というヘッダに乗せる必要があります。このとき、区切り文字の `&` は `,` に置換します。画像データ本体は `multipart/form-data` でアップロードします。

アップロードが成功するとJSONデータが返ります。その中から `media_id` という値を取得して、覚えておきます。

画像は4枚までアップロードできるので、必要な回数繰り返します。最大4個の `media_id` を取得します。

**本文をツイートする**

通常通り、ツイートのAPI https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status= を使用します。

リクエストパラメータに、前工程で取得したメディアIDを `&media_ids=aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc,ddddd` の様に付け加えます。カンマ区切りで最大4個です。

こうしてできたパラメータを、普通のツイートと同じ手順で、OAuthの署名を行います。上にも書きましたが `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` でPOSTします。